# Create BloomFilter in GCP Dataflow Job JAVA

Tags: java, apache-beam, dataflow, bloom-filter

I have some records called "IDs" (about 2 Billion rows of Strings). I would like to create a BloomFilter based on these IDs, in GCP dataflow job. Then, I would like to iterate another data record called "newIDs", to check whether the newIDs are within the IDs or not.

My idea was to get the PCollectionView of these IDs as an Iterable. Then, based on this PCollectionView, I am going to create a BloomFilter, and this BloomFilter will be viewed as a Singleton for all the instances. Is this the best way to do it?

If yes, how can I make a global BloomFilter based on a PCollectionView > and use it for all the instances? I know sideInput for the DoFn; however, in my DoFn of generating the BloomFilter, there was no input. I just want to iterate the PCollectionView> and generate the BloomFilter.

Here are the codes:

```
// Generate the PCollectionView<Iterable<String>> from the IDs file;
PCollectionView<Iterable<String>> IDs = p.apply(TextIO.read("IDs file")).apply(View.asIterable());

// I don't know how I should write the code to generate this BloomFilter View. I tried the code below.
PCollectionView<BloomFilter<String>> bloomFilter = ???
PCollectionView<BloomFilter<String>> bloomFilter = p.apply(ParDo.of(new MakeBF()).withSideInput(IDs));

// Like here, I don't know what I should use as input for DoFn.
private class MakeBF extends DoFn<???, BloomFilter<String>> {
Iterable<String> IDView = c.sideInput(IDs);
BloomFilter bloomFilter = BloomFilter.create(Funnels.stringFunnel(Charset.defaultCharset()), (long) 2E9, 0.001)
IDView.forEach(id -> bloomFilter.put(id))
}
```

Thanks a lot, guys.

Comment: You say that you want "to check whether the newIDs are within the IDs or not“. Be aware that a bloom filter may give you false positives.

Comment: I know there is FPP, however, I just want to know the ones that are not within the set for sure. I think BF is perfect for me.

Comment: What is a size of your Bloom filter? Is it going to to be modified while your pipeline will be running?